# Page background scrolls but div doesn't

Tags: jquery, html, css

Url is: http://themediafixer.com/main.php?p=home

If you resize the window so some of the content is cropped at the bottom, the scrollbar only moves the page background instead of the actual content. There are three elements in this page whose css settings are probably creating this issue, but I'm not sure which one to adjust to fix this error (`#section, .items, div.pane`).

I'm using jQuery tools to make the panes scroll if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#all` div wrapping everything has `position: fixed`. You need to remove that or change it to `position: static`.